# Get Drupal SEO friendly URL based on node id?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drupal

We have an ASP.NET MVC app that sits on top of a Drupal database (MySQL). Right now this app creates a newsletter and works pretty darn well. However, right now we're constructing the URL's like so:

```
http://baseurl/node/<node-id>
```

The problem is that the client actually wants the SEO friendly URL instead of this direct URL. Like so:

```
http://baseurl/news/2012/9/hi-guys-this-is-just-a-test
```

What's the best way to get this URL? Is it stored in the database? Only accessible through Drupal specific methods? Should a web service be created in Drupal to take in a node id and return the friendly URL? Something else?

What do you think?

Comment: [`url()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/url/7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module. It allows automatic SEO friendly link generation from all kind of properties of the node, including the node id.

In your specific case you'll need to access the generated URL from the Drupal database using ASP.net. Don't know about the means to access databases in ASP.net, but you will have to query the `url_alias` table. That table will contain a mapping between the the original URL (`node/1234`) and the generated URL.

Answer (score 0):

Rolf...nice answer. That actually allowed me to do a query to get URL aliases for all nodes by using the following:

```
SELECT n.nid, ua.dst FROM node AS n INNER JOIN url_alias AS ua ON ua.src = CONCAT('node/', n.nid);
```

Or can just do a single SELECT if looking for *1* item and do a WHERE condition on /node/{id}

...works like a charm.